# security/ir.model.access.csv could not be processed: No matching record found for external id

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14, odoo-15, odoo-server

Exception: Module loading tailor_management_sys failed: file tailor_management_sys\security/ir.model.access.csv could not be processed:
No matching record found for external id 'model_tailor_production_target' in field 'Model'
Missing required value for the field 'Model' (model_id)

> **here is my ir.model.access.csv**
> id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
> access_tailor_production_target,tailor_production_target,model_tailor_production_target,base.group_user,1,1,1,1

> **here is my model file which is"*tailor_production_target.py*" code is below**

```
class tailor_production_target(models.Model):
    _name = 'tailor.production.target'
    _description = 'tailor_management_sys_production_target'

    target_id = fields.Integer(string="Target id")
```

> **i have added it in *manifest file and also in init* of the model i also have double checked the sequence and typo error, all was right but still i am getting this  server error.**

Comment: Seems that there is an error in the module that doesn't load the python model.

Comment: what should i do to resolve this out.

Comment: I don't know, I don't have a way to test this out. Look at the odoo startup logs when you restart the service to see if there is any errors

Comment: no there is not any error when i restart the server or upgrade the module and any warning appear in the startup log

Comment: Check if you imported the `tailor_production_target.py` file, It should be imported in ***__init__.py*** file

Comment: i checked i also have noticed that if i do any changes in .py file of any model (like changing the fields name etc. also in xml side but it does not reflect on server side )they are not reflecting on server after server restarting

Comment: Please share the module structure with  all ***__init__.py*** files

Comment: thanks for support it's resolved after restarting my pc it starts working.